# How can we automatically "save and exit" the current tabs in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

I have planned to change my browser from Mozilla Firefox to IE8, but in IE8 it is not possible for me to save and exit on a sudden close of the browser so that I can restore my previous tabs safely. But it is there in all versions of Firefox.

I have tried in the settings but didn't anything there.

Comment: upon searching i got the answer now. 
pls visit 
http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-restore-last-browsing-session-in-ie8/

Comment: Write your comment above as an answer and mark it as accepted since it is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why on earth would you like to switch to IE 8 from Mozilla?

IE has for some time been a bit conservative about implementing new featers, e.g. it took them years to finally implement a simple tab bar. If you really checked the preferences in IE8 It may very well be that the feature you're looking for does not (yet?) exist.

If you want to leave Mozilla I suggest you try another sophisticated browster instead of falling back to IE8. Try for example
Opera http://www.opera.com/ or
Chrome http://www.google.ch/chrome

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Why not recommend trying IE9 RC? It is quite competitive with FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: Simple answer: back then IE9 did not yet exist... ;)